SpeadSheetView bottom corner radius not changing
I have this SpreadSheetView in my swift controller to show the data in a tabular form. The bottom corner radius are only being applied when I do not give padding to the view, but without the padding the table isn't expanding to the full height and is making the table scrollable vertically (which I do not want).
How I am initializing and setting it's height -
 func setupSpreadsheetView() {
    spreadSheetView = SpreadsheetView()
    spreadSheetView.dataSource = self 
    spreadSheetView.delegate = self
    spreadSheetView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false              spreadSheetView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
    spreadSheetView.bounces = false         
    spreadSheetView.gridStyle = .solid(width: 1.0, color: .fieldsBGColor)         spreadSheetView.register(HeaderCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: String(describing: HeaderCell.self))        
   spreadSheetView.register(TextCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: String(describing: TextCell.self))         
    spreadSheetView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
 }

Inside calculating size of the cell function -
var ht = max(height, 35)
        print("height of cell -> \(ht)")
        finalHeight += ht
        if row == data.count {
            setSpreadsheetHeight()
            print("height of sheet -> \(finalHeight)")
        }
        return ht

And finally setting the height of SpreadSheetView with additional 15 padding -
 spreadSheetView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
      
         NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
               spreadSheetView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: finalHeight + 15)
           ])
        spreadSheetView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        spreadSheetView.layer.masksToBounds = true

Final view with 15 padding (not showing bottom radius) -

View without 15 padding (shows radius but scrolls vertically which I do not intend to have) -

Removing the padding shows radius but if you look carefully, the content is just at the bottom and it scrolls vertically a bit.
Tried removing padding, changing height, but still bottom radius seems to be an issue.
